# Cutting a string into pieces

Tags: c++, string, scanf

How can I extract pieces from this string?

I have a file that contains:

```
0065445 APPLE$456
089464 MANGO$489
0012389 GUAVA$744
```

What I want to do is input the file line by line, then cut the string into some pieces.

- 0065455 Will go in a struct `a[0].num`
- APPLE will go in struct `a[0].name`
- 456 will go in struct `a[0].dollar`

And similarly for other lines.

Everything is working fine, but it's not successfully getting the dollar part into its variable.

Here's the code:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main(){

FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

char str[80] ;

struct abc{
int num;
char name[20];
int dollar;
};

int i = 0;

while(fgets(str,79,fp)!=NULL){

struct abc a[i] ;

sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s$%d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);

cout <<i+1 <<") Number : "<<a[i].num<<" Name :  "<< a[i].name <<" Dollar : "<< a[i].dollar << endl ;
i++;

}

return 0 ;
}
/* These didn't work too.
sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s %d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);
sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s%d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);
sscanf(str,"%d %s$%d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);

*/
```

There's 1 more problem: the first part of string is an int that starts with 0, but the zero is not being accepted in the int. How to do it?

This is working as I want now but still after parasing the string into an int I am not getting the zeroes:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std ;

int main(){

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

    char str[80] ;
    char temp[80] ;
    struct abc{
        int num;
        char name[20];
        int dollar;
    };

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0 ;

    while(fgets(str,79,fp)!=NULL){
        i = 0;
        j = 0 ;
        struct abc a[i] ;

        char* ptr = 0; // this is used as a helper variable to strtok

        ptr = strtok(str, " $\n"); // we specify the delimiters here

        while (ptr != NULL) 
        {
            if (j == 0){
                strcpy(temp, ptr);
                a[i].num = atoi(temp);
            }
            if (j == 1)
                strcpy(a[i].name, ptr);

            if (j == 2){
                strcpy(temp, ptr);
                a[i].dollar = atoi(temp);
            }

            ptr = strtok(NULL, " $\n");
            j++;
        }

        cout <<i+1 <<") Number : "<<a[i].num<<" Name :  "<< a[i].name <<" Dollar : "<< a[i].dollar << endl ;
        i++;
    }

    return 0 ;
}

/* These didn't work either.
sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s %d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);
sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s%d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);
sscanf(str,"%d %s$%d\n",&a[i].num,a[i].name,&a[i].dollar);

*/
```

Comment: Do you mean `0065455 will go in a struct a[0].num`? (as opposed to `a[0].int`)

Comment: sscanf "stops scanning" when it gets a hit on the `[^$]`. You need a second sscanf that starts where you left off (number of characters read is returned by sscanf), then read the value after the $ sign.

Comment: He wants to extract the string in three pieces, the logic is he should find first `space`, second `$` from `0065445 APPLE$456` , and he will get the `0065445`, `APPLE` and `456`

Comment: I was not provided with space it was a question in a contest

Comment: Floris
sscanf(str,"%d %[^$]s",&a[i].num,a[i].name);
sscanf(str,"%d\n",&a[i].dollar);
This is not working either

Comment: is there a reason you need to do this in c??

Comment: You have to point to a new place in `str` (right after the `'$'`), not the beginning. Second statement should be `sscanf(str+strchr(str, '$') + 1, "%d", &a[i].dollar);`

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend that you remember to close your file after you're done reading... It's good practice.

Comment: I don't  know c++ very good yet

Comment: Yes forgot the close thanks every one

Comment: Thanks Floris will try it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `0's` will not show up when you print the integer `a[i].num`.

You could make `a[i].num` a string (`char[]`) or an integer array. to make the `0's` show up. you can parse it as an integer (via `atoi(str)`), if you need it to be used otherwsie.

Comment: OK the 0's will remain in there after parase ?

Comment: well, you could loop through the string until you find the first non-zero, then parse starting there.

Comment: use atoi(str) to convert string to integer. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: I did but the 0's are still not getting in the int. are you saying that I should use the string for the zeroes.

Comment: yes, use a string because it will store any kind of char (including 0-9).  then when you print the string, it will include the 0s.  then, if you ever need to actually treat a[i].num as an integer, you can use atoi(str) starting at the first non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the C++ tag, I'd do things a little differently. First I'd overload the stream extractor operator for your `abc` type:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, abc &a) { 
    is >> a.num;
    std::getline(is, a.name, '$');
    return is >> a.dollar;
}
```

Then you can use that to read in a file of records, such as:

```
abc temp;

std::vector<abc> a;

std::ifstream in("input.txt");

while (in >> temp)
    a.push_back(temp);
```

Or, you can use an `istream_iterator` to initialize a vector directly from the stream:

```
std::vector<abc> a((std::istream_iterator<abc>(in)),
                    std::istream_iterator<abc>());
```

The easiest way to keep the leading zeros on the first number is probably to change it from an `int` to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

Here is a simple code (C only) that prints your strings separately (I recommended a similar solution in another post).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcpy and strtok
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi
int main()
{
    char input [25] = "0065445 APPLE$4056"; // input string

    // storage for the separate parts of the string
    char line[10]; 
    char fruit[10];
    char number[10];

    char* ptr = 0; // this is used as a helper variable to strtok

    ptr = strtok(input, " $\n"); // we specify the delimiters here
    int i = 0;
    // I'm using i here as a control variable so that during each iteration different part
    // of the string is saved
    while (ptr != NULL) 
    {
        if (i == 0)
            strcpy(line, ptr);

        if (i == 1)
            strcpy(fruit, ptr);

        if (i == 2)
            strcpy(number, ptr);

        ptr = strtok(NULL, " $\n");
        i++;      
    }

    printf("%s %s %s\n", line, fruit, number);

    return 0;
}
```

Some sample output:

```
$ ./a.out 
0065445 APPLE 4056
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes thank you ! I tried strtok in my contest but I did't rememberd it correctly . Thank you buddy

Comment: But is it bad to use in c++ too

Comment: Well, C++ is a **very** different language from C, best to stick to C++ way of doing things for something like this if you can write it in C++.

Comment: bro I took the 0065445 in a string then used atoi to get it into int but still the starting 0's are'nt getting stored in the int

Comment: Oh, sorry I've misunderstood you, I thought you wanted to strip them, will update the question. It will need to be in a string in this case.

Comment: Thanks Its done . I know now that the ints can not store zeros at the beginning

Comment: If you need to display the leading zeroes but still store them as ints, maybe you can think about printing them like this `printf("%06d\n", num);` although again C++'s formatting facilities are a lot better.

Comment: Let me know if I've missed some aspect of your question.

Comment: Also if you're happy with my answer I wouldn't mind it if you were to accept it by clicking on the tick next to it :)

Comment: Just under my vote count for the question there should be a check that you can tick like so - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
struct abc{ int num; std::string name; int dollar; };
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream file("input");
    abc st1;
    std::string l;
    while (file >> st1.num >> l) {
        if (size_t p = l.find_first_of('$')) {
            st1.name = l.substr(0, p);
            std::istringstream(l.substr(p+1)) >> st1.dollar;
            std::cout << st1.num << " : "
                << st1.name << " : " << st1.dollar << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```